# Single-threading in Websphere application

Tags: websphere

In CICS we have something called a ENQ command which is useful for single-threading based on desired values . Similarly do we have anything in Websphere?
ie., I want my MDB to read multiple messages from the input queue. However I want to process the messages strictly in the received order. Setting the value of 'Server session' in the activation spec property to 1 will achieve this but I want to do it programatically within my MDB

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quote from [JMS 1.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7195-jms-1.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). It seems that ordering is only guaranteed if you send messages from a single session; in that case the sessions input message stream will be ordered. Since no API exists for limiting session count, I guess you must depend on server facilities for this configuration.

> 4.4.10 Message Order JMS clients need to understand when they can depend on message order and when they cannot.
>
> ￼4.4.10.1 Order of Message Receipt Messages consumed by a session
>   define a serial order. This order is important because it defines the
>   effect of message acknowledgment. See Section 4.4.11 ”Message
>   Acknowledgment,” for more details. The messages for each of a
>   session’s consumers are interleaved in a session’s input message
>   stream. JMS defines that messages sent by a session to a destination
>   must be received in the order in which they were sent (see Section
>   4.4.10.2 ”Order of Message Sends,” for a few qualifications). This defines a partial ordering constraint on a session’s input message
>   stream. JMS does not define order of message receipt across
>   destinations or across a destination’s messages sent from multiple
>   sessions. This aspect of a session’s input message stream order is
>   timing-dependent. **It is not under application control**.

Comment: I guess I will put my requirements in a different way. here it goes:  2 messages arrive at 2 different instances of an MDB. The messages contain a reference ID(to update a DB using the ref ID). Hence I want to process one at a time ie., issue a lock on the reference ID, process the first message and then process the second one. And of course messages coming with a different reference ID will be processed by other threads.